# QGIS GRASS r.neighbor neighborhoodsize

Tags: qgis-3, grass-gis, r.neighbor

I work with QGIS 3.16 and am a rookie.

I need to do an neighborhood analysis of a raster, to know how many and which cells have a specific value (1) in the radius of 700 ha. My cellsize/pixels in the raster are 25mx25m.

I want to use r.neighbor (operation sum) but which neighborhood size do I take?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, to clarify, the window size in `r.neighbors` is the width of the window (length measure) in pixels, but you request an area measure in hectares. If you mean a window width size such that the window covers 700 ha, then we can do some quick arithmetic:

Each pixel in your raster is 625 mq.meters. If we choose a window of 106, then the window will cover: (106*106) * 625 = 7022500 sq.meters, or 702 ha.

Returning to your question, you asked for the count of cells with value 1. Here I would create a new raster with all values except 1 set to null, then use the r.neighbors `method=count` to obtain a new raster with the count of value 1 in that (very large) neighborhood.

And one further comment: with such a large window, maybe it would make more sense to create a **vector** grid of 2600 meters (each vector polygon in the grid would be ~700 ha), then use `v.rast.stats` to extract a variety of raster values: sum, count, etc for each vector grid cell from the raster.